# Update items for multiple users when editing together metal React in Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a list where multiple users can edit simultaneously. I have linked Firabse database and someone can create an item, etc. The others get to see this only with a change, only the person who changes something only sees the change and the other people see the old item and the change, which makes it duplicate .

Is there a possibility to run a fuction again when changing the firebase database?

this is my current code:

```
        componentWillMount() {
          
          
          this.setState({
            personalItems:[],
            inactiveItems:[],
             sprintItems:[],
             /*currentSprint:this.props.data.sprintNumber,*/
             user:Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
          })
    this.fetchItems();
    }


  fetchItems(){
    this.setState({
      personalItems:[],
      inactiveItems:[],
       sprintItems:[],
    })
      let ref = Firebase.database().ref('/items/');
      ref.on('value' , snapshot => {
          snapshot.forEach((childSnap) => {
          let state = childSnap.val();
    

          var newelement = {author: state.author, title: state.title, status: state.status, key: state.key, user: state.user, match: state.match, x: state.x, y: state.y, public: state.public, notes:state.notes, participants: state.participants, bgcolor: state.bgcolor, category: state.category, selectedkeycat: state.selectedkeycat, sprint: parseFloat(state.sprint), zIndex: state.zIndex };
          this.setState(prevState => ({
            
            personalItems: [...prevState.personalItems, newelement],
          }));
        });

          
      
      })

  }

    onDrop(object){
      this.setState({
        personalItems:[],
        inactiveItems:[],
         sprintItems:[],
      });
  
      Firebase.database().ref('/items/'+object.match).update({
        author: object.author,
        status: 'active',
        key: object.key,
        title: object.title,
        public: "true",
        match: object.match,
        notes: object.notes,
        user: object.user,
        x: this.state.position.x,
        y: this.state.position.y,
        sprint: this.state.sprint,
        zIndex: object.zIndex
        
    }).then((data)=>{    
this.fetchItems();

    }).catch((error)=>{
        //error callback
        console.log('error ' , error)
    })

    }
```

So when the component is loaded, the items are downloaded and that works. Then when a change is made the function 'onDrop' activates it changes the variables in the database and then has to reload the items. However, this only happens to the person doing this but not to the other users who see the item 2x the old and the new one while the arrays are being emptied.

I have also tried with componentDidUpdate only then I can't call setState.

Does anyone have an idea for the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to call `this.fetchItems` again when the user writes a new item to the database. Since you attach a listener with `ref.on('value'` when the component is mounted, that listener will stay active and keep listening to changes in the database.

So:

```
onDrop(object){
  this.setState({
    personalItems:[],
    inactiveItems:[],
     sprintItems:[],
  });

  Firebase.database().ref('/items/'+object.match).update({
    author: object.author,
    status: 'active',
    key: object.key,
    title: object.title,
    public: "true",
    match: object.match,
    notes: object.notes,
    user: object.user,
    x: this.state.position.x,
    y: this.state.position.y,
    sprint: this.state.sprint,
    zIndex: object.zIndex        
  }).catch((error)=>{
    console.log('error ' , error)
  })
}
```